# Multiply list of matrices by list of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of vectors and a list of matrices for each vector, what i need is to multiply each list of matrices to respective vector.

```
v = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}};

U = {
{{{U1a11, U1a12}, {U1a21, U1a22}}, 
 {{U2a11, U2a12}, {U2a21, U2a22}},
 {{U3a11, U3a12}, {U3a21, U3a22}},
 {{U4a11, U4a12}, {U4a21, U4a22}}}},
{{{U1b11, U1b12}, {U1b21, U1b22}},
 {{U2b11, U2b12}, {U2b21, U2b22}}, 
 {{U3b11, U3b12}, {U3b21, U3b22}}, 
 {{U4b11, U4b12}, {U4b21, U4b22}}}, 
{{{U1c11, U1c12}, {U1c21, U1c22}}, 
 {{U2c11, U2c12}, {U2c21, U2c22}},
 {{U3c11, U3c12}, {U3c21, U3c22}}, 
 {{U4c11, U4c12}, {U4c21, U4c22}}}
};
```

I know that I can use a `Do`

```
vt = ConstantArray[0, {Length[U], Length[v]}];

Do[vt[[it]] = (#.v[[it]]) & /@ U[[it]], {it, 1, 3}]

vt
```

But I don't want to use a `Do` cycle. Is
there a way to do it in an intelligent way?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few alternatives to `MapThread`, with `res = MapThread[Dot, {U, v}]` from Dr. belisarius' answer,

```
res1 = Dot @@@ Transpose[{U, v}];
res2 = Dot @@@ Thread[{U, v}];
res3 = Thread[dot[U, v]] /. dot -> Dot;
res4 = Activate[Thread[Inactive[Dot][U,v]]] (* if you have version 10 *);
Equal @@ {res1, res2, res3, res4, res}
```

> True

Comment: +1 I particularly hate the `Thread[dot[U, v]] /. dot -> Dot` thing. It is needed in a lot of situations (like the `testxxxQ` functions) and it makes me feel soooo uncomfortable

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I can't agree more. Thank you for the vote.

Answer (score 6):

```
v = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}};

U = {
   {{{U1a11, U1a12}, {U1a21, U1a22}}, {{U2a11, U2a12}, {U2a21, U2a22}},  
    {{U3a11, U3a12}, {U3a21, U3a22}}, {{U4a11, U4a12}, {U4a21, U4a22}}}, 
   {{{U1b11, U1b12}, {U1b21, U1b22}}, {{U2b11, U2b12}, {U2b21, U2b22}},
    {{U3b11, U3b12}, {U3b21, U3b22}}, {{U4b11, U4b12}, {U4b21,U4b22}}}, 
   {{{U1c11, U1c12}, {U1c21, U1c22}}, {{U2c11, U2c12}, {U2c21, U2c22}}, 
    {{U3c11, U3c12}, {U3c21, U3c22}}, {{U4c11, U4c12}, {U4c21, U4c22}}}};

res = MapThread[#1.#2 &, {U, v}];

Map[MatrixForm, res, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why not just `Dot` instead of wrapping it in an additional pure function call with `#1.#2&`?

Comment: @MartinBüttner No special reason. I feel more comfortable with it, and the problem is small enough to hardly justify trying to measure performance subtleties

Comment: @MartinBüttner Now, thinking again about why I tend to use it like this, see kglr's answer with the `Thread[dot[U, v]] /. dot -> Dot` horrible construction. `Thread` and `Dot` are a nasty marriage and I guess that one develops allergies to the simple sight of them together. I'm using `MapThread` here, but probably my running nose doesn't discriminate